# Entity Framework Code First - Firebird migration: No MigrationSqlGenerator?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, firebird

I'm searching for a way to update my firebird-database. I tried using migrations:

```
    private void btnUpdateDb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DbConnection userDBConnection = ClassBasicRepository.GetDBConnection();

        var configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(
            userDBConnection.ConnectionString,
            "FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient");

        DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
        migrator.Update();
    }
```

DbMigrationsConfiguration:

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<BaseDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        //SetSqlGenerator("FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient", new FirebirdSql.Data.Entity.???);
    }

    protected override void Seed(BaseDbContext context)
    {
        MigrationsAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        MigrationsNamespace = "MyServices.Data.Migrations";
    }
}
```

"migrator.Update()" gives me the following Exception:

> No MigrationSqlGenerator found for provider 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient'. Use the SetSqlGenerator method in the target migrations configuration class to register additional SQL generators.

I have to specify a MigrationSQLGenerator in the Configuration. But I can't find it in the FirebirdClient.dll. The only solution I found was to rewrite it on my own:
https://github.com/mrward/entityframework-sharpdevelop/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Migrations/Sql/SqlCeMigrationSqlGenerator.cs

Is a Firebird specific MigrationSQLGenerator really necessary and not not provided to enable migrations?

My Environment:
EntityFramework 5.0.0
.NET 4.5
FirebirdClient 3.0.2.0

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that migrations are not (yet) supportet by the FirebirdClient.dll. But what is the alternative? Plain SQL? See: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-506

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are currently not supported. Actually you can use migrations, but you'll have to generate the script and change it to fit Firebird-flavor SQL.

Comment: do you have an example this workaround to get migrations to run?

Comment: Huh, this answer is two years old. Migrations are now supported (though not released yet - probably in week or so). But you can have it: https://github.com/cincuranet/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/tree/migrations.