# Entity Framework Firebird MigrationSqlGenerator: Deactivate Transaction for Create and Insert in one Table?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, firebird

As mentioned here [Entity Framework Code First - Firebird migration: No MigrationSqlGenerator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853226/entity-framework-code-first-firebird-migration-no-migrationsqlgenerator) I'm trying to enable Migrations on my Firebird-Database.

for that purpose I'm writing the following implementation of the "MigrationSqlGenerator" (not finished!):

```
public class FirebirdMigrationSQLGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override DbConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        return DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient").CreateConnection();
    }

    protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
    {
        using (var writer = Writer())
        {
            WriteCreateTable(createTableOperation, writer);

            Statement(writer.InnerWriter.ToString(), true);
        }
    }

    private void WriteCreateTable(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("CREATE TABLE " + Name(createTableOperation.Name) + " (");
        writer.Indent++;

        var columnCount = createTableOperation.Columns.Count();

        createTableOperation.Columns.Each(
            (c, i) =>
            {
                Generate(c, writer);

                if (i < columnCount - 1)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(",");
                }
            });

        if (createTableOperation.PrimaryKey != null)
        {
            writer.Write(", PRIMARY KEY ");

            writer.Write("(");
            writer.Write(createTableOperation.PrimaryKey.Columns.Join(Quote));
            writer.WriteLine(")");
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteLine();
        }

        writer.Indent--;
        writer.Write(")");
    }

    private void Generate(ColumnModel column, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {

        writer.Write(Quote(column.Name));
        writer.Write(" ");
        writer.Write(BuildColumnType(column));

        if ((column.IsNullable != null)
            && !column.IsNullable.Value)
        {
            writer.Write(" NOT NULL");
        }

        if (column.DefaultValue != null)
        {
            writer.Write(" DEFAULT ");
            writer.Write(Generate((dynamic)column.DefaultValue));
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(column.DefaultValueSql))
        {
            writer.Write(" DEFAULT ");
            writer.Write(column.DefaultValueSql);
        }
    }

    protected override void Generate(InsertHistoryOperation op)
    {
        using (var writer = Writer())
        {
            WriteinsertHistory(op, writer);
            Statement(writer.InnerWriter.ToString(), true);
        }

    }

    private void WriteinsertHistory(InsertHistoryOperation insertHistoryOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        StringBuilder model = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (byte item in insertHistoryOperation.Model)
            model.Append(item.ToString("X2"));

        writer.Write("INSERT INTO \"" + insertHistoryOperation.Table.ToUpper() + "\" (migrationId, model, productVersion) ");
        writer.Write(" values ( '{0}', '{1}', '{2}') ",
                          insertHistoryOperation.MigrationId,
                  "0x" + model.ToString(),
                  insertHistoryOperation.ProductVersion);

    }

    protected override string Quote(string identifier)
    {
        return identifier.Replace("PK_dbo.", "").ToUpper();
    }

    protected override string Name(string inString)
    {
        return "\"" + inString.Replace("dbo.", "").ToUpper() + "\"";
    }

    protected override string BuildColumnType(ColumnModel column)
    {
        String colType = base.BuildColumnType(column);
        if (colType == "INT")
            colType = "INTEGER";
        return colType;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the __MigrationHistory table is created uppercase. But since the "HistoryContext" is not, the first SELECT-Statement is throwing an Exception:

```
SELECT 
"A"."A1" AS "C1"
FROM ( SELECT 
COUNT("B"."A1") AS "A1"
FROM ( SELECT 
    1 AS "A1"
    FROM "__MigrationHistory" AS "B"
)  AS "B"
)  AS "A"
```

Normaly I would insert "modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove()" 
into the Context, but the HistroyContext is part of the framework and can't be changed...

Any ideas?
My Environment: EntityFramework 5.0.0 .NET 4.5 FirebirdClient 3.0.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firebird tablenames are only case sensitive when quoted, so you either need to stop quoting tablenames (both on creation and in queries), or you need to stop upper casing tablenames and use them as is.

For example issueing a `CREATE TABLE xyz ( ... )` will create a table `XYZ` that can be accessed using `SELECT * FROM xyz`, but also with `XyZ`,`XYZ` and `"XYZ"`. It cannot be accessed using `"xyz"`.

Creating a table as `CREATE TABLE "xyz" ( ... )` wil create a table `xyz`, which can only be accessed using `SELECT * FROM "xyz"`, but not with `xyz` (no quotes) or any other combination of casing and with or without quotes. On the other hand `CREATE TABLE "XYZ" ( ... )` can be accessed using `SELECT * FROM xyz` and `"XYZ"`, and any other case without quoting, but not with `SELECT * FROM "xyz"`.

As far as I can tell from your code, you are creating tables unquoted in `WriteCreateTable`, therefor the name is stored uppercase, but you are inserting into them quoted. You may also want to look into the contract/expectations of the `Quote` and `Name` methods, as it looks to me like you got their implementation reversed (`Quote` does what `Name` should do and vice versa).