# Making Firebird work with Entity Framework Code First and Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, firebird, firebird-embedded

I am getting this error, when typing enable-migrations in packagemanager.

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with
>   invariant name 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient'. Make sure the
>   provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the
>   application config file. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

This is what i done so far:

- Downloaded the 32 Bit embedded firebird from:
  http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5-2-upd1/
- Extracted the dll's to my solutions: http://d.pr/i/Hsgv
- Added reference to FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient: http://d.pr/i/7SiO

Made this DataContext class:

```
class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public static FbConnection connection
    {
        get
        {
            FbConnectionStringBuilder b = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
            b.ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded;
            b.UserID = "SYSDBA";
            b.Password = "masterkey";
            b.Dialect = 3;
            b.Database = "D:\\cafw.fdb";
            b.Charset = "WIN1251";
            b.ClientLibrary = "fbembed.dll";

            return  new FbConnection(b.ToString());
        }
    }


    public DataContext()
        : base(connection, true)
    {

    }
}
```

Note that this is a console application, so i have no app.config file to add the provider, and the database doesn't actually exist, was hoping it created that for me :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Code First - Firebird migration: No MigrationSqlGenerator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853226/entity-framework-code-first-firebird-migration-no-migrationsqlgenerator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firebird ado.net drive does not support code First Migrations.

Comment: For more information see [Entity Framework Code First - Firebird migration: No MigrationSqlGenerator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853226/entity-framework-code-first-firebird-migration-no-migrationsqlgenerator) and [Support for EF's Migrations](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-506)

Comment: Well, It does for some time.